# Do I need to create an object to sort by my "number" element?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, sorting

My file numbering system just rolled over 100,000 which is causing some issues. Namely it causes programs to organize #100,000 before #99,999 because it sees the 1 first.

For example, another program would read the files in ascending order like this:

> XXXX_100000_XXXXXX.file
>
> XXXX_10001_XXXXXX.file
>
> XXXX_99999_XXXXXX.file

But it should go:

> XXXX_10001_XXXXXX.file
>
> XXXX_99999_XXXXXX.file
>
> XXXX_100000_XXXXXX.file

I have a function that reads all the files, sorts them by number, and puts them in a new array in order. Here's some pseudo code:

```
while(my directory has more files)

//this entire chunk assigns the number part of the filename to an int
string filename = my file
string num = filename[5] through filename[11]    
//checks if the number is 5 digits, if yes, removes the underscore
if(num at position [11] == "_"){ 
num = num[5] through num[10]
}
int fileNum = num.toInteger

//now I have the number as an int
```

**EDIT:
I just realized I could much more easily get the number by calling `.Split` on the filename and converting `arr[1]` to an `int`. I'll leave the old code for fun though.**

Here's where I'm stuck. I want to feed these into a new array, sorted, or make the array sortable after everything is in there.

Do I need to create an object with the filename and number as elements, feed all the objects in, and then sort the array by number? I know that would work, but I can't help but thinking there's a more efficient way of doing this.

I don't need code written for me, I just need help working out the algorithm logic, or if my way is already the best way, let me know!

Comment: What's the element type of the array? You can populate it unsorted and call `Array.Sort(array, elemToFileNum)` where `elemToFileNum` is a function/delegate of type `Elem => int`.

Comment: @Lee It's a `ZipEntry.FileName`, which I believe is string, though the documentation for the Zip library I'm forced to use is garbage. So that function will do the work for me that I wrote out above; find the integer, and sort by it? That seems too good to be true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an unsorted array of file names e.g.

```
string[] fileNames = ...
```

and a function for extracting the number from the name e.g.

```
public static int GetFileNumber(string myfile) {
    string num = filename[5] through filename[11]    
    //checks if the number is 5 digits, if yes, removes the underscore
    if(num at position [11] == "_"){ 
    num = num[5] through num[10]
    }
    return num.toInteger
}
```

then you can sort them using [`Array.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf.aspx):

```
Array.Sort(fileNames, (f1, f2) => GetFileNumber(f1).CompareTo(GetFileNumber(f2)));
```

Comment: So that's performing an insertion sort on my starting array of files based on the FileNumber that I found previously?

Comment: @coinbird - Yes it will order the elements based on the result of `GetFileNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using an int array for the number and string array for filename and then push it to collection and in the end sort the collection?

Create the collection with
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections

And then sort the collection with 
https://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2011/05/07/sorting-collections-in-c/

Sorry if I was not much of a help.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the string-list using an "Alphanumeric sort". This will put "100" after "9".

Example: https://www.dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting